# Flash Deep-Linking Causing Page Refresh in Web-Kit

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, deep-linking

I am working on a project where my team's Flash application is being displayed in another team's Web-Kit browser.  We are experiencing a bug when a Flash Accordions selected index is changed; the web-page itself refreshes.  Since this is a map-based application, this is unacceptable since the users Area of Interest is lost.

From my research so far, I understand that Flash uses "Deep-Linking" to set the state of the Flash App based on "fragments" in the url without actually refreshing the page.  So, a change in the Accordion's selected index updates the url, and uses that url to do stuff without actually refreshing the page.

Since this is not a problem in any other browser (FF,IE,Chrome,Safari), the incompatibility seems to be with the Deep-Linking and the Web-Kit.  Both teams are actively troubleshooting, but time is running out.  Does anyone know of a method to disable the url from changing while still achieving the desired result (i.e. the accordion still changes panels)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `historyManagementEnabled` property of the `Accordion` to `false`.

[Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Accordion.html#historyManagementEnabled) page for the Accordion class.